# What is the recommended/standard install path for apache-tomcat on a linux box

Tags: java, linux, tomcat

Hello I am looking to install Apache-Tomcat on a RedHat linux and I am interested if there is a standard place for this to be installed. in other work I have seen tomcat installed at

/opt/apache-tomcat-[VERSION]/

but I would expect it to be found under /usr.
Best answer will have a link to authoritative site.

Thanks so much,

David.

Comment: I've done more googling around and found a couple of different HOWTO which suggest on putting it in a couple of different places /user/local /user/share /opt. Looks like there is no agreed place where this lives.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know if there's such a thing as an "official" place, but a reasonable thing to do would be to do what you've done and refer to tomcat through a softlink at /usr/local/tomcat or some such, which would allow you to upgrade versions by simply installing a new version in opt and changing the softlink.

Answer (score 9):

It depends on who you ask, but I see it this way:

/opt is typically for third-party add-on software.  /usr/ is often for 'system' software.  User compiled apps go in /usr/local.

I put tomcat in /opt/apache-tomcat-VERSION.  I then make a symlink to it as /opt/tomcat.

The [Linux Standards Base](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/en/LSB) may have more info on the matter.

Answer (score 3):

There's a Red Hat RPM package for Tomcat 6 - just "yum install tomcat6" and it will put everything in the right place for you and fix up the security by running Tomcat as a dedicated user (not to mention taking care of updates and patches by putting Tomcat into the RPM repository).

Most of the executables, the configuration and the webapp directory end up under /var/lib/tomcat6 using this method.

Answer (score 2):

Someone else mentioned http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html, which is good information. Unfortunately, they didn't provide any accompanying information with it, aside from a snarky comment.

According to that document, /opt is where installed software would go, so I would recommend /opt/tomcat, and set *CATALINA_HOME* to this directory.

It also says /var is where variable data would go, so I would put it in /var/tomcat and set *CATALINA_BASE* to this directory.

I'll add a little background. If you don't set *CATALINA_BASE*, then it will default to the same as *CATALINA_HOME*. However, *CATALINA_HOME* should be the unadulterated install, and should be set as read-only. You should use a different location for variable stuff like your actual web directories and logs. Then, when you need to change versions, it's just as simple as changing *CATALINA_HOME*. Also, you can run multiple instances of Tomcat more easily without having multiple copies of the same install.

Also, don't forget to create a CATALINA_BASE/bin/setenv.sh (or .bat for Windows) file instead of editing CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh (or .bat for Windows).

Yeah, this is more information than anyone asked for, but hopefully someone will find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is an easy answer for that here, too bad nobody of these high-pointers have listed it:

http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html

Comment: it is very informative, but definitely doesn't give an easy answer :-) However one can read and understand and use that understanding to design their own approach, if they are given enough time by their clients. I was trying to do a manual install and first I thought to mimic the directory structure followed by apt-get installation of tomcat9, but it felt quite hard to understand and remember. I felt it also deviates from the standard set forth by above article in some places. I guess it is suitable only for an automated installer like apt but not fit for manual install I was doing.

Comment: I followed something closer to the answer given by @Jamie as I didn't have much time to spend on reading this full doc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain it doesn't matter.

Just like most well-behaved Java apps look for the *JAVA_HOME* environment variable to locate the preferred Java installation, once you've set *CATALINA_HOME* in either .bashrc or .profile of the affected users, software needing to locate Tomcat should be able to find it.

Comment: Truth - it doesn't matter, except when it does. The root of the question for me is not so much how to (easily) make a particular install path work, but rather how much administrative effort is involved over the lifetime of the install. The opinions of FSHS group are useful, but even they point out competing ideas. The opinions of a package installer (if used) are even more relevant - why would I argue with `yum`? Then, the opinions of the community count, too, as I want less "impedance mismatch" between help guidance and my own install.